# Laravel - Como paginar e dar Order By

Tags: php, laravel-5

Tenho esse código:

```
$modeloVideo = ModeloVideo::paginate(10);
```

Quero paginar por 10 e exibir `order by desc` (ordem decrescente).

Como fazer essa query?

Tentei assim :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\ModeloVideo;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function home() {


        //TODOS OS REGISTROS DA TABELA
    $modeloVideo = ModeloVideo::all()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

        $array = array("videos" => $modeloVideo,
        );

        return view('home',$array);
    }
```

Código do model:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ModeloVideo extends Model {
    //informando a tabela que sera usada
    protected $table = "modeloVideo";
    //quando fizer uma insercao ou update nao adicionar a coluna created ou update




}

?>
```

e ainda não funcionou, da o erro:
BadMethodCallException
Method orderBy does not exist.

Comment: Não tenho como testar agora, mas acredito que com `ModeloVideo::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(10);` deve funcionar, mas você receberá um `LengthAwarePaginator` e terá que tratar... utilize o `dd();` para testar. Qual a versão do laravel você está utilizando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar a busca com o `orderBy` e o `paginate` basta utilizar a seguinte sintaxe:

```
ModeloVideo::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Assim como essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19885982/9671639) e  [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29580206/9671639) no SOen.

Answer (score 1):

***Evite fazer assim, somente alguns casos:***

```
$modeloVideo = ModeloVideo::all()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

porque, você está trazendo no `all()` [todos os registro na base de dados em uma classe collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-collections) e depois tem um erro porque não existe [orderBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-models) na classe [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-collections) o comando é [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortby) e por fim gera uma paginação, **então** está ***tudo errado***, porque, já trazer a massa de dados (todos os registros) da base para depois fazer ordenação e paginação gera um grande gargalo na sua aplicação. A `SQL` construida para esse comando é: `SELECT * FROM modelo_video`.

***Modo correto:*** primeiro ordena valores da base e depois faz a paginação tudo isso já vindo pronto os dados da sua tabela, ou seja, na `SQL` escrita pelo `framework` `Eloquent`, **exemplo**:

```
$modeloVideo = ModeloVideo::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

e a  `SQL` construida para esse comando (basicamente falando) é: `SELECT * FROM modelo_video ORDER BY created_at DESC limit 10 offset 0`, e esse dado já vem a quantidade especifica e essa é a grande diferença. ***Observação:*** *essa `SQL` é um exemplo, o método paginate busca informações para pagina em várias do próprio `Framework`, isso é mesmo para exemplificar a parte do gargalo*.

Answer (score -2):

antes de usar o `orderBy` você precisa buscar os registros no banco:

```
ModeloVideo::all()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

`->all()`: busca todos os registros do banco

`->orderBy`: ordena os valores buscados

para a paginação você precisará usar o método `->paginate`, veja o exemplo na [documentação oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results)

> O erro é causado porque o método `orderBy` não faz parte de instancias de `Model` e sim de `collections`.

Comment: Não consegui entender, pode digitar a query completa que atenda essa condição por favor? $modeloVideo = ModeloVideo::paginate(10); quero paginar por 10 e exibir order by desc

Comment: atualizei a resposta Deny

Comment: Obrigado, mas ainda não funcionou, atualizei a resposta com o código.

Comment: publique qual foi o erro que encontrou...

Comment: BadMethodCallException
Method orderBy does not exist.

Comment: valeu o do santo will deu certo era só tirar o all()